# Python .xls to .xlsx conversion with all formatting intact

Tags: python, excel

I have a bunch of .xls files with cells colored, formatted. 
I need to convert them to xlsx format having all the formatting intact. Could anyone please  let me know wat is the best way to do it? Thanks

Comment: any particular reason you want to do it in Python?

Comment: Via Excel automation?

Comment: i already have a script which runs specified instructions and generates xls files. It is easier to convert than changing whole script using openpyxl.

Comment: I agree with Tim Williams. For that, if you need to stick to Python, use xlwings. But really, you will probably be better off converting your whole script to XlsxWriter. Its API is closer to xlwt's than OpenPyXL's.